# Do we have the structure "should have been doing" (advice in the past) in everyday English conversation?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, syntactic-analysis

Ok, according to [this website](http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/modal-verbs-of-obligation.html) :

"**should**" can be used to show mild obligation or advice

Ex: *You should save some money.*

"**should have + pp**" can be used to show advice in the past (that past action didn't happen)

Ex: *You should have gone to bed earlier, now you have missed the train.*

After spending 3 days googling, we found that we also had the structure "**should + be + verb-ing**" to express that [the subject is not fulfilling their obligation or is not acting sensibly.](http://www.grammar.cl/english/should.htm)

Ex: *You should be wearing your seatbelt. (The person isn't wearing one right now)*

*We should be studying for the test. (We are not studying right now and we should)*

This seems to make sense because "**be verb-ing**" expresses an ongoing action.

My question is that:

Do we have the structure "**should have been doing**" (advice in the past) in everyday English conversation?

Can we say:

Ex: *You should have been wearing your seatbelt at the time the plane took off. (The person wasn't wearing one at that moment & we said this to express a regret in the past)*

**Note**: I couldn't find any source on the internet mentioning this, so could you please include a referenced source in your answers?

Comment: 'I shouldn't have been out playing football, I should have been working on my essay' is fine. / This is hardly 'advice in the past'; it is 'evaluation of correctness {of a durative action in the past}' epistemic modal usage.

Comment: Yes, "should have been" is fine grammatically. Here's a [link](http://gonaturalenglish.com/explain-about-could-have-been-would-have-been-and-should-have-been-in-english-grammar/), as requested.

Comment: I should have been = I ought to have been.